# Wake on lan with MacBook Air 2018?

Tags: macbook-pro, wake-on-lan

is it possible to use wake on lan via wifi on the macbook air 2018?

What iOS app (or terminal command?) can you recommend to use?

I want to wake of the MacBook Air with my iPhone which is in the same network.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look to this article: 
http://osxdaily.com/2013/12/14/wake-on-lan-mac-iphone/
Let me know if it is useful

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.